# Различия форм на основе JDialog и JFrame?

Tags: jframe, java, jdialog, swing

Создаю приложение в NetBeans. Использую конструктор форм. Хотелось бы узнать, в чем основные отличия форм, созданных из JFrame и JDialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если посмотреть иерархию наследования, то становится понятно, что frame - базовый класс для всех окон, - самый общий вариант использования. Им можно пользоватся в любой ситуации. Диалог же сам по себе это просто частный случае frame. уверен его предназначение это воспомагательные функции, - info/warning/error message box, input dialog, open/save file dialog, etc... + функции модальных окон

Answer (score 2):

Разница такая же как между просто [окном](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81) и [диалоговым окном](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE) в WIMP-идеологии.

Answer (score 1):

Сравнил, у **JFrame** есть метод **setIconImage(Image image)**, позволяющий определять ему иконку, а в основном **JDialog** наследуется от **Dialog**, где есть метод **setModal()**, который позволяет ему быть модальным, в **JFrame** такого нет, уверен отличий ещё много, щас народ подтянется.

Answer (score 1):

не стоит использовать JDialog вместо JFrame, если ему не выставить alwaysOnTop то пользователь может потерять его, ибо в панели задач он не отображается, а если выставить - понятно что будет